# saving hibernate entity with multiple objects of same type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I save the below entity, it is duplicating the same value in another object:

For example, from my struts project (the screen) if i change the value of field **shipmentShipper** then **shipmentConsignee** is also updated with the same value.

Struts Config:

```
<struts>

<package name="orderManagement" namespace="/orderManagement" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="OrderManagementAction" class="com.logistics.actions.orderManagement.OrderManagementAction" method="executeOnLoad">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/orderManagment/orderManagement.jsp</result>
        <result name="list">/WEB-INF/pages/orderManagment/orderManagementList.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

</struts>
```

Action Class:

```
package com.logistics.actions.orderManagement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.dsiksjane.actions.base.BaseAction;
import com.dsiksjane.actions.login.LoginCO;
import com.dsiksjane.beans.LoginBean;
import com.dsiksjane.beans.common.LookupBean;
import com.dsiksjane.common.CommonConstants;
import com.logistics.entities.customers.Customers;
import com.logistics.entities.orderManagement.Orders;
import com.logistics.service.customers.ICustomersService;
import com.logistics.service.orderManagement.IOrderManagementService;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * 
 * @author Sikandar Mahmood
 *
 */
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderManagementAction extends BaseAction {

private OrderManagementCO orderManagementCO = new OrderManagementCO();

private List<LookupBean> orderTypeList = new ArrayList<LookupBean>();

private List<Customers> customersList = new ArrayList<Customers>();

private List<Customers> agentsList = new ArrayList<Customers>();

private List<Customers> portsList = new ArrayList<Customers>();

@Autowired
private IOrderManagementService service;

@Autowired
private ICustomersService customerService;

/**
 * On Load method
 * @return
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public String executeOnLoad() throws Exception {

    String actionCommand = (String) getRequestParameter("actionCommand") == null ? SUCCESS : (String) getRequestParameter("actionCommand");
    
    switch (actionCommand) {
    
    case SUCCESS:
        init();
        //orderManagementCO.setOrder(null);
        setPage(SUCCESS);
        break;
        
    case CLEAR:
        init();
        orderManagementCO.setOrder(null);
        setPage(SUCCESS);
        break;


    case EDIT_RECORD:
        init();
        Long id = Long.parseLong( (String) getRequestParameter("id") );
        Orders order = service.getOrder(id);
        orderManagementCO.setOrder(order);
        setPage(SUCCESS);
        break;
    
    case LIST:
        List<Orders> orders = service.getMainList();
        getRequest().setAttribute("objectList", orders );
        setPage(LIST);
        break;
    
    case SUBMIT:
        LoginCO loginCO = ((LoginCO) getSessionMap().get("loginCO"));
        LoginBean loggedInUser = loginCO.getUserBean();
        if( loggedInUser == null )
            return ERROR;
        
        service.save(orderManagementCO, loggedInUser);
        setPage(SUCCESS);
        break;

    default: // do nothing..

    }

    return getPage();

}


/**
 * This method fills the default values for the page being loaded... 
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public void fillDefaultValues() throws Exception {
    getDefaultValueOrderType();
}

public String getDefaultValueOrderType() throws Exception {
    String defaultOrderType = getBaseService().getDefaultLookupValue(CommonConstants.LOOKUP_TABLE_ORDER_TYPES);
    return defaultOrderType;
}

/**
 * Initialization of page
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void init() throws Exception {
    
    setOrderTypeList(getBaseService().getLookupByTable(CommonConstants.LOOKUP_TABLE_ORDER_TYPES));
    
    setCustomersList( getCustomerService().getMainList() );
    
    setAgentsList( getCustomerService().getAgentsList() );
    
    setPortsList( getCustomerService().getPortsList() );

    fillDefaultValues();
    
}

}
```

Entity:

```
package com.logistics.entities.orderManagement;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

import com.dsiksjane.beans.common.NecessaryFields;
import com.logistics.entities.customers.Customers;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name="orders") 
@Getter
@Setter
public class Orders extends NecessaryFields {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="consignee_ntn")
    private String consigneeNtn;

    /**
     * Clearing Agent
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)   
    @JoinColumn(name="clearing_agent_name")
    private Customers clearingAgentName;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="shipment_shipper")
    private Customers shipmentShipper;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="shipment_consignee")
    private Customers shipmentConsignee;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="shipment_notify_party")
    private Customers shipmentNotifyParty;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="shipment_forwarder")
    private Customers shipmentForwarder;


    @Column(name="clearing_agent_challan")
    private String clearingAgentChallan;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_details_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private OrdersDetail orderDetails;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private OrdersAddress orderAddress;

}
```

The repository class:

```
@Service
public class OrderManagementService implements IOrderManagementService {

    @Autowired
    private IOrderManagementDAO dao;

    @Override
    public OrderManagementCO save(OrderManagementCO orderManagementCO, LoginBean loggedInUser) throws Exception {
    
        Orders obj = orderManagementCO.getOrder();
    
        if( obj.getId() != null ) {
            obj.setUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getUserName());
            obj.setUpdatedDate( new java.util.Date() );
        } else {
            obj.setCreatedBy(loggedInUser.getUserName());
            obj.setCreatedDate( new java.util.Date() );
            obj.setCompanyId( loggedInUser.getCompanyId() );
        }
    
        dao.save( obj ); 
    
        return orderManagementCO;
    }
}
```

Fields mapping in JSP (working fine):

```
<s:select id="selectShipper" class="custom-field"
name="orderManagementCO.order.shipmentShipper.id" 
label="Service Type" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Shipper" 
list="%{customersList}" listKey="id" listValue="fullName" />

<s:select id="selectConsignee" class="custom-field"
name="orderManagementCO.order.shipmentConsignee.id" 
label="Consignee" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Consignee" 
list="%{customersList}" listKey="id" listValue="fullName" />
```

Please check in the screenshot, i changed shipper as C4 and saved. Consignee was also selected as C4. And please note that both selects are populated with same data list. (customersList)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `value` attribute in your `<s:select>` tag, and that should have the value that you have sent to backend. May be something like `value="%{orderManagementCO.order.shipmentShipper.id}"` and for the other one it should be `value="%{orderManagementCO.order.shipmentConsignee.id}"`.

Comment: When I send from frontend the data goes fine in network tab, but in the struts action it is not same as sent in request. May be when the entity is retrieved from the database, the sub-entity inside it is not fetched correctlly, is the entity confused to fetch the correct one ?

Comment: just curious about the `OrderManagementCO` structure, can you please attach that as well.